# Are there iPad handwriting apps that allow you to insert space between lines?

Tags: ios, ipad, notes.app, handwriting, stylus

I prefer to take notes and design code by hand. There are several good apps (Penultimate, Readability, Noteshelf, etc.), but they all seem to lack something I really wish they had: the ability to add space in the middle of the document, between lines.

Most or all of the handwriting apps I've used have a selection tool, but none of them allow you to insert text in the middle of the document.

As an example, imagine you've handwritten this list:

- First
- Second
- Fourth

Oops: you forgot to write "Third." You tell the app to add space between Second and Fourth (which pushes the rest of the document down). Then you add it such that the list now looks like this:

- First
- Second
- Third
- Fourth

Does anyone know of an app that affords this?

Answer (score 1):

MyScript Notes Mobile has that feature. It's pretty neat. You just press on blank space where you want the lines to split, and a "shift" pop-up appears. When you select that, a line appears that lets you move all the writing beneath it up or down as far as you want within the page's limits.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for! How is the "ink" in that app? Does it look as good as, say, Penultimate?

Comment: Ink is nice and smooth, not as smooth as Penultimate or the other other top handwriting apps, but the features, including conversion to text, are so good, I keep coming back. There's a free demo called Myscript Memo.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Microsoft OneNote for iPad. The text forms almost as nicely as Penultimate with slight pressure sensitivity.

Comment: Text forms almost as nicely as Penultimate, slight pressure sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

I think no App Engineer already encountered such a feature Request for his App.

Most of the time users just write on pad like on paper so what do you do on this problem on Paper? (write it at the end of list and use a arrow or footnotes etc.)

Sure it would be nice to have this Feature so if i were at Your Position i would write this as a Feature Request to the App Developer(s).